# How to change string to variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to change string to variable, please some one help me.
this is a string >> `{"method":"setValue","params":{"cmd_Motor":true}}`

I wan to change like this:
[image]

Comment: I want to convert like this: https://imgur.com/O3miplm

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Looks like the question actually should be why is request.body a string and not an object. http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html or the request is not setting the correct content type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
const input = '{"method":"setValue","params":{"cmd_Motor":true}}';
const result = JSON.parse(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but you can convert a string to a JSON object and you can also convert a JSON object to a string:

**converting from string to json**

```js
const myString = '{"method":"setValue","params":{"cmd_Motor":true}}';
const myJson = JSON.parse(myString);

console.log(myJson.method) // setValue
console.log(myJson.params.cmd_Motor) // true
```

****converting from json to string****

```js
const myJson = { method: 'setValue', params: { cmd_Motor: true } };
const myString = JSON.stringify(myJson);

console.log(myString);
```

Comment: JSON is a string. So _"converting from string to json"_ doesn't make sense

Comment: thank you so much, that is i want of result